# Best method to call WS with SQL

Tags: sql-server, web-services

I am finding the best method to call a WS when I have a update in my sql server in one column. With trigger?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> > [what is] the best method to call a WS when I have a update in my sql server in one column. With trigger?

From the trigger write a row to a separate table, or Service Broker queue, and then from a separate program read from that table or queue and call your web service.